# how get session from EncryptedSessionId in magneto

Tags: php, magento, session

i give session id to third party using :-

```
Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->getEncryptedSessionId();
```

Then it  will automatically  hit my magento custom  controller/action and pass **EncryptedSessionId** as parameter . By using that session id it give automatically follwing  json response.

```
{"first_name": "xyz", "last_name": "zzz", "email": "xxx@gmail.com","uid": "12jlkd1k2","phone_no":" +x xxx-xxx-xxxx"};
```

any idea about that how to decrypted Session Id in magento and get customer data please help me.

Comment: Try this code `Mage::getModel('core/encryption')->decrypt($data);`

Comment: instated of that, i have use Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array( 'value' => $sessId ));                                                                                                                    it`s working i got customer data to related session.

Comment: sorry this are  [ Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array( 'value' => $sessId ));   ]  not working.its work only in same browser if user logged.